# Execution order of JavaScript/jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of jQuery code as follow. When the button with id `some_button` is clicked, it gets some data (which is HTML code) from an url and then put the HTML it gets into `some_div`. The HTML it gets contains some buttons with class `run` and I want this buttons to be triggered automatically. With the following code, the `run` buttons are never trigger automatically when `some_button` is clicked for the first time, but works when it's clicked the second time. Another strange thing I notice is, when I use Chrome break points to step through the code, I find that it executes `$(".run").trigger("click");` before executing `$("#some_div").empty();` and `$("#some_div").append(data.info);`. Why is it executed in this order?

```
$("#some_button").click(function()
{
    //some code here
    $.get("/some_url", function(data){
      $("#some_div").empty();
      $("#some_div").append(data.info); 
    });
    $(".run").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for $.get? You should look at the done function: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ (if using later than jquery 1.8 see then instead)

Comment: Just put it in the asynchronous callback where you have used `data`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs on get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) might help you with this.

```
$("#some_button").click(function()
{
    //some code here
    $.get("/some_url", function(data){
      $("#some_div").empty();
      $("#some_div").append(data.info); 
    }).done(function() {
       $(".run").trigger("click");
    });    
});
```

In addition, `$.get()` implements the promise interface so you can leverage the `.then();` functionality as well...